# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Math\Rand' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
<?php

use Zend\Crypt\Key\Derivation\Pbkdf2;
use Zend\Math\Rand;

Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();

include("config.php");

$test=uniqid(rand());

echo $test;

$pass = 'password';
$salt = Rand::getBytes(32, true);
$key  = Pbkdf2::calc('sha256', $pass, $salt, 10000, 32);

printf ("Original password: %s\n", $pass);
printf ("Derived key (hex): %s\n", bin2hex($key));

?>
```

I have installed Zend Framework with xampp and now I cannot use any of its classes
It always shows an error like below

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Math\Rand' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\test.php on line 15

Please guide me. I am using the framework for the first time.

Comment: Have you imported the folder in your project? How does your folder structure look like?

Comment: which folder?? i have included the zend files.. and the project file structure is myzend/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library

Comment: Are you installing zf2 via composer? That should be preferred technique because it takes care of autoloading for you.

Comment: Yes i have installed using composer

Comment: Thanks. there was a problem in folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder structure had a problem so it was not working. 
Now i have changed the path and its working fine.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to include the autoloader.

Check out the `index.php` file from the skeleton application, and you'll see they do this before running the application:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

```
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';
```

The autoloader knows how to go load classes for you based on the namespaces.

Comment: i tried including the autoloader but still doesnt work. after including the autoloader it gives the following error

Comment: Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\myzend\vendor/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\myzend\init_autoloader.php on line 43

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myzend\vendor/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\myzend\init_autoloader.php on line 43

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myzend\init_autoloader.php on line 44